# Vue.js parent component check children components

Tags: vue.js

Just get stuck with components issue...

I have a parent component called "Notifications" and within it I have components called "Note" with v-for that runs based on some global variable in main file.

What I need to do is to check a variable inside the childs components for each of them, from the parent component or from the children components...

The variable is flag of true-false that make me know how much components are shown and how much disappered

I tried $children and $ref - but without success... hope someone will open up my eyes :)

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: If you're managing state, you can look into [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex).

Comment: You may be better off rearchitecting so that the parent component doesn't need to check the contents of its child components -- i.e. have "Notifications" read the global variable to determine how many "Note" components to instantiate.  "Note" components would then only need to care about their own individual note, not the rest of the context.

Comment: can you pass the variable to the child components using props in the child?